# What aircraft has the highest critical Mach number?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, transonic

What aircraft has the highest critical Mach number? The highest I heard of was BAC/English Electric Lightning at Mach 0.95. Are there planes with higher Mcrit. and is it plausible to go higher than that in a manned plane?

Note: Critical Mach number is the lowest flight Mach number when the speed of sound is reached locally on the airframe.

Comment: I don't think you mean [critical Mach number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_Mach_number). Are you asking about cruise speed? Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/17189/14897

Comment: Yes, I definetly mean critical mach number. The title is odd, I know, that's for getting attention ':)

Comment: Then please ask precisely what you want to know. If you disagree with my editing, feel free to roll back, but be aware that you will risk to have the question closed.